# Pyomo:How to declare the nodes network in power flow model?

Tags: python, optimization, pyomo

I am new to pyomo. I am trying to build a power flow model in pyomo based on the existing GAMS code.

GAMS can declare the relations of each node easily in the power flow model, and I am confused about how can I declare the same network in PYOMO?

The existing GAMS code:
[image]

The five-bus network flows and directions
[image]

Anyone can helps me with this? Many thanks !!